# How to import from module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-2016

One library exports its function in such way:

```
export {
    default,
    sitemapBuilder,
    routesParser,
    pathsFilter,
    paramsApplier,
} from './lib';
```

I would like to import them by single line:

```
import { Sitemap, routesParser } from 'react-router-sitemap';
```

But it doesn't work, `Sitemap` and `routesParser` are undefined.

From their guide:

```
import Sitemap from 'react-router-sitemap';
import { routesParser as parseRoutes } from 'react-router-sitemap';
```

`Sitemap` is class
`routesParser` is function

Actual result:

`Sitemap` loaded ok
`parseRoutes` is undefined

Comment: But in your worked code, how the same library exported `Sitemap` and `routesParser` by default ?

Comment: Thanks, man. You are right. I have updated the question. Check it very below.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this to import in single line

`import Sitemap, { routesParser } from 'react-router-sitemap';`

Answer (score 0):

Import everything like below,

```
import * as parseRoutes from 'react-router-sitemap';
eg: console.log(parseRoutes.sitemapBuilder());
```

Or Import something like below,

```
import { sitemapBuilder, routesParser } from 'react-router-sitemap';
```